# Thinned yogurt instead of milk

Tags: substitutions, bread

A tortilla bread recipe calls for 3/4 cup milk, is it okay to use yogurt which is thinned by water?

> Flour 2 cups
>    Baking powder 1 and 1/2 tsp
>      Salt  1/2 tsp
>   Oil 2 tbsp
>   Warm milk 3/4 cup

Many other recipes call for water instead, but I believe milk makes the bread softer and affect the texture. That's why I'd use yogurt.

Comment: Wait... 1.5 cups of baking powder? That can't be right.

Comment: @derobert: Ooops, I meant to write "tsp"! Sorry, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yogurt will work just fine. It will even give you some nice extra flavor.

Unless it is greek yogurt you don't need to thin it at all. Greek yogurt has some water drained off but normal yogurt has the same water content as the milk it was made from.

In some recipes you might have to thin it to get the right consistency to work with but in the case of flour doughs you can just mix it into the dough straight.

Answer (score 7):

Yogurt is acidic, much more so than milk. So when you substitute it for milk, you're affecting the acid-base balance in your recipe, and you may need to change some of the baking powder to baking soda to restore it.

Comment: Beat me to the punch.  Given the amount of baking soda present in this recipe, I think it'd be okay, but I'd be very cautious about applying this rule in other recipes.  The pH change could have a more substantial effect on rising through its effect on yeast and structural proteins, and definitely (implied by this answer) on recipes calling for very little baking powder or soda.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be fine using thinned yoghurt. You are correct in your belief that milk (or rather, fat of any kind) softens the dough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only problem is that it must be warm milk, so should I add warm water to yogurt or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Add warm water, yes. That's common sense isn't it?